# Send instant message on Office Communicator using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to send instant message using Office Communicator and Excel VBA. I use an excel sheet containing a list of Email IDs.

```
**A            B    C**
Serial No   Name    Email
1            abc    abc.abc@abc.com
2            xyz    xyz.xyz@xyz.com
3            pqr    pqr.pqr@pqr.com
```

I wrote the below code to send message. But it is not working. I have enabled Communicator reference in VBA.

```
Sub sendIM()
Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
Dim ToUser As String
Dim message As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    On Error Resume Next
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
                ToUser = Chr(34) & cell.Value & Chr(34)
                'MsgBox ToUser
                message = "Hi " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "HOW ARE YOU"
                Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(ToUser)
                msgr.SendText (message)
        End If
    Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For a single email id, it is working. I use the below mentioned code to send single message.

```
Sub sendIM()
Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
Dim ToUser As String
Dim message As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ToUser = "abc.abc@abc.com"
message = "hai"
On Error Resume Next
Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(ToUser)
msgr.SendText (message)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I need to loop through the sheet so that the message is sending to everyone.  What changes I have to make this work ?

*Note: The Email Ids here I mentioned is not real.*

Comment: >`Note: The Email Ids here I mentioned is not real.` Really? Damn! I was planning to spam `abc.abc@abc.com` :P

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked with `Office Communicator` but since you are saying that the second code works then try this. (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub SendIM()
    Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
    Dim ToUser As String, message As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws
        '~~> Why On Error Resume next? If you know what error you are going to get
        '~~> Then simply handle it. For the time being, I am skipping the record
        '~~> Also keeping it out of the loop
        On Error GoTo SkipIT

        For Each aCell In .Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If aCell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
                ToUser = aCell.Value '<~~ Don't need quotes
                message = "Hi " & .Cells(aCell.Row, "B").Value _
                          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                          "HOW ARE YOU"
                Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(ToUser)
                msgr.SendText (message)

                DoEvents '<~~ Let excel send the message. Give it time
            End If
SkipIT:
        Next aCell
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

An improved version. Takes care of error handling

```
Sub sendIM()
    Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
    Dim ToUser As String, message As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws
        For Each aCell In .Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If aCell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
                ToUser = aCell.Value '<~~ Don't need quotes
                message = "Hi " & .Cells(aCell.Row, "B").Value _
                          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                          "HOW ARE YOU"

                '~~> Only place I can think an error could happen
                On Error Resume Next
                Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(ToUser)

                '~~> Check if the object is created
                If Not msgr Is Nothing Then msgr.SendText (message)
                Set msgr = Nothing
                On Error GoTo 0

                DoEvents '<~~ Let excel send the message. Give it time
            End If
        Next aCell
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```